# "Morgen habe ich ____ Geburtstag", "meinem" or "meinen"?

Tags: dative, accusative

In a phrase

> Morgen habe ich ___ Geburtstag

do I need *meinen* because of *haben* or *meinem* because of *morgen*? Can't really understand the exact usage of dative with time yet, but I'm inclined to the dative. Is this right?

Comment: Why would "morgen" require a dative anywhere? Can you provide another exam0le where that is the case?

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: To an English speaker at least, since there are three nouns if you count *Morgen*, it might seem that there must be an indirect object somewhere. There are, of course, several reasons that this is incorrect, but I can see how it might be confusing for a beginner. Part of the problem may be putting the subject after the verb, which seems odd if you're coming from an SVO language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct phrase is

> Morgen habe ich meinen Geburstag.

"meinen Geburtstag" is an object of the verb "haben", and as such, its case is governed by the verb.

For "haben", the thing being possessed is stated in accusative case, so that is the case "meinen Geburtstag" appears in here.

---

Note that while your sentence does not sound very unnatural, either of the following might be preferrable for being somewhat more concise:

- Morgen habe ich Geburtstag.
- Morgen ist mein Geburtstag.